# How to express the "new" operator of C++ logic in go?

Tags: go

I have a structure like this

```
type Node struct {
    data int
    next *Node
}

var root Node;
```

I would like to create a tmp Node and pass the address to root.next, how to write this kind of logic in go?

```
root.next = Node
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what the question is here, but maybe read the [Go tour chapter on pointers](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1)?

Comment: With [new](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) you can do this `root.next = new(Node)`.

Comment: This is exactly what I need!

Comment: BTW, what's the difference between root.next = new(Node) and root.next = &Node{}? Both could work I think

Comment: @AdamLee in this case they are the same, but the literal expression allows you to set a values contents if you need to. https://play.golang.org/p/9_oUDBw3R-

Answer (score 1):

There are no constructors in Go. You just create an object by using the type name and you can set the fields at the same time.

```
tmp := Node {
    data: 1
}
root.next = &tmp
```

You can also take a pointer to a new object.

```
tmp := &Node {
    data: 1
}
root.next = tmp
```

And then put it all together.

```
root.next = &Node {
    data: 1
}
```

There is also a `new` operator which is equivalent to `&Node{}` and therefore it is not very convienent as you need to assign field values later.

Comment: BTW, what's the difference between = and :=?

Comment: @AdamLee see https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments

Comment: get it, in my case, seems no need to use := since next is already defined.